# Why can I invoke a private method on an instance of the sub-class when it shouldn't be visible to the instance?

Tags: java, polymorphism, instance, private

This question is similar to [Why can a "private" method be accessed from a different instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900632/why-can-a-private-method-be-accessed-from-a-different-instance)

I am convinced with the answer there. The code should run. However when I change the code to be like this

```
class Horse extends Animals{
}

public class Animals {

    private void eat(){
        System.out.println("Generic Eating");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animals h = new Horse();
        h.eat();
    }

}
```

when I try to use polymorphism to invoke the private method eat() on the Sub-class Horse it works and calls the method of the parent class.

- doesn't java dynamically call the instance specific method of the class?
- shouldn't this throw a runtime exception?
- does this mean the method is actually inherited but not normally accessible?

Comment: Are these classes defined in the same file?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Does that matter?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, files are irrelevant for anything related to visibility of members.

Comment: @BrunoReis Not so.  For example, `private` members of an inner class are visible to the parent.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, are you talking about *inner classes* or *classes defined within the same file*? Because these are 2 very different concepts. If you talk about *inner classes*, then obviously they need to be defined within the same file, because one must be defined within the other. And Java doesn't support class definition spanning multiple files. As you can see in the question, it is *definitely* not about an inner class. So again, it doesn't matter. Finally, calling the outer class "parent" is very imprecise... This kind of discussion needs to be extremely precise, otherwise it's pointless

Comment: @BrunoReis They're not different concepts; one is an example of the other.  I don't think the OP knows what an inner class is, and it is not clear from the question that one of these classes is not an inner class of the other.  The OP's code isn't compilable as posted, so it's obviously an incomplete copy-paste.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, do you see `class Animals { class Horse ... {...}}`? Or do you see `class Horse ... {} class Animals {}`? They are completely different things, I hope you agree with that. In the first, `Horse` is an inner class of `Animals`. In the second, it is not. Finally, you probably didn't try to compile, did you? It's perfectly compilable. Just go ahead and try it. Create a file called `Animals.java` in any directory, and copy-and-paste that sample code. Then run `javac Animals.java`. Boom, compiled.

Comment: @BrunoReis You're right, I didn't try to compile.  I didn't know that it was even possible to define a class *outside* the public class that shares its name with the file.  Useless knowledge, of course, since that's obviously something one should never do.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, I'm glad you learned something new :) But I would advise you against completely dismissing something that you just learned with *"Useless knowledge, [...] obviously something one should never do"*. Think about it: 5 minutes ago you thought it was impossible -- there might be other things that you don't know are possible and that could leverage that "feature" for good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, *a `Horse` **is an** `Animal`*. So yes, a `Horse` has one method called `eat`, because every `Animal` has one such method, and every `Horse` is an `Animal`.

The method `eat` was defined by the class `Animal`, and is a private method in that class. Which means it can only be accessed from within other methods defined in the `Animal` class, and nothing else. No super-/sub-classes, no wrappers, no containers, no nothing. Not even a `Horse` which, even though *it **is an** `Animal`*, it is not `Animal` itself.

So your example works in the way it was expected to work.

---

As a final note, answering specifically to the question in the "title",

> Why can I invoke a private method on an instance of the sub-class when it shouldn't be visible to the instance?

The only thing that matters is *from where* you are invoking that private method. You are invoking it from within the class in which it was defined. Therefore it is accessible.